# Remove curly braces array notation from postgresql in scrapy

Tags: postgresql, scrapy

I'm trying to remove the curly braces from Scrapy's scraped output when stored in Postgresql. This is what my crawler processing is doing now:

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=NewsScrapesItem(), response=response)
    l.default_output_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), replace_escape_chars, remove_tags)

    l.add_xpath('art_title', '//*[@id="s_view_top"]/h2')
    l.add_xpath('art_body', '//*[@id="newsview"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/text()')
    l.add_xpath('art_category', '//*[@id="s_nevi"]/a[2]/text()')
    l.add_value('art_url', response.url)
    yield l.load_item()
```

Whether I'm calling text() or not, or seemingly no matter how it is processed, the output looks something like the below in the database.

{"Supercomputing comes handy in quest for COVID-19 cure"}

How can I get rid of the brackets, which I believe are array notation? I'm using SQLAlchemy for the postgres pipeline. Another post here has mentioned something like:

```
    SELECT unnest(xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml)::varchar[]);
```

for parsing XML, but I don't know how that applies to Scrapy processing.

EDIT: ALL fields in the postgres database end up surrounded by curly braces, even things like:

```
    l.add_value('newspaper', 'Japan Times - English')
```

Ends up as:

{"Japan Times - English"}

This is the first time I've scraped anything to postgres, so no idea what is going on.

Comment: totally depends on what data you are extracting from the site. You can also setup better cleaning for each field with your own [ItemLoaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-item-loaders) (which you are already using)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand about what data. ALL database fields end up surrounded by curly braces, no matter the site or html being scraped.

Comment: Change your `default_output_processor` to use also `TakeFirst` to take only one input element, turning the 1-element lists you are currently extracting into strings.

Comment: I tried that, but all it does is limit what the crawler returns to the first letter of each string. If I get rid of text(), then TakeFirst limits what is recovered to < or some other tag/character.

Answer (score 0):

`xpath()` returns an array, if you know your expression only returns a single element, you can select just that element. No need to use unnest()

```
select (xpath('/id/text()', '<id>45687</id>'::xml))[1]::text
```

The cast to `::text` is needed because otherwise it would be an `xml` type.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea how to use that in a Scrapy context. I’m not using that kind of SELECT statement anywhere.